# How to query python list with multiple characters in each one

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I know the title is a little messy and if someone wants to fix it, they are more than welcome to.

Anyways, I'm having trouble querying a python list with multiple values, I have looked on other Stackoverflow questions and none of seem to match what I'm looking for.

So, this is the code I have so far, its supposed to use a for loop statement, so that it goes through each character and then uses and if in statements to check whether a character in the user input matches anything in the list.

In my example, it only uses symbols, but hopefully that shouldn't be much of a problem

Anyways here is the code

```
string = input("What symbol character would you like to check")
symbols=[' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '"', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~',"'"]
def symbol():
    for string in symbols:
        if string in symbols:
            return True
        elif string not in symbols:
            return False

if symbol():
    print('ok')
if not symbol():
    print('What Happened?')
```

*Update, I also need solution to be able to accept letters and numbers as well as the symbols.

For example, if user enters !a, that it will still detect the '!' and evaluate to True.

Comment: You need to pass the user input to `symbol` function, and you need to use that to compare against the values in `symbols`. Apart from that you cannot `return` immediately, after checking one character.

Comment: ah, yes, I did that before, but forgot to change it back, I'll tell you if it works

Comment: you don't need `for` loop to check it - `if string in symbols: print('ok') else print('What Happened?')`

Comment: Hi furas, I get this error if I do that - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    if string in symbols():
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: `symbol()` is a function, whereas `symbols` is a list. And you shouldn't name your variable `string`.

Comment: Efferalgan, I agree with you on the variable naming. Trying to think of a better name.

Comment: Hi furas, your solution actually works, I removed only the for loop and everything works fine. I'll probably paste my solution in, so this question can be marked as solved.

Comment: The list is defined as symbols and the function is symbol without the s. I'll probably change the name the function as well.

Comment: Hi everyone, I  deleted my answer because I realised that there is a flaw in the code. I need to be able to allow other characters not in list. So if the user types in something like !a, it would still detect the symbol and result in True. It seems the current solution only works if the symbol is the only character in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you loop over the input string, you should be able to get the solution you're looking for.  How about something like this?

```
input_string = raw_input("What symbol character would you like to check? ")
symbols = [' ', '!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '"', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~',"'"]
def symbol(input_str):
    for char in input_str:
        if char in symbols:
            return True
    return False

if symbol(input_string):
    print('ok')
else:
    print('What Happened?')
```

`raw_input()` avoids some trouble.  Before I changed that, I was getting an `unexpected EOF while parsing` error.  I changed the names of your variables to help a bit and avoid potential conflicts.

By moving the `return False` line outside the `for` loop, it lets the loop check every character in the input string first.  If it checks every one, and nothing matches, then it will default to returning `False`.

Also, you have two calls to `symbol()` in your question, which I don't think is necessary.  One `if` can check for a `True` return value.  Lacking that, we move to the `else` statement and can safely know that the function returned `False`.

Comment: Hi coralv. Just marked your solution as the best answer. Oh, and regarding the two calls to symbol, it was my way of checking whether the code worked. It just gives me the extra bit of reassurance, you know?

Comment: Also, I'm using Python 3, but your solution still works. :)